# The equation $ |z-1| = 5* |z-i|$ represents the equation of circle or elipse?

Tags: complex-numbers

The equation $ |z-1| = 5* |z-i|$ represents the equation of circle or elipse ?

My approach :

Let $|z| = (a+ib) \implies$ $|(a-1) + ib| = 5*|a+(b-1)i|$

$\therefore$ I get $24a^2 + 24b^2 +2a -50b +49 =0$ on solving, which represents an equation of a circle. Am I correct? Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Apollonius circles.

Answer (score 2):

Hint we can write it as $$\frac{|z-1|}{|z-i|}=5$$ so z are all points which are at constant distance from a point on $X,Y$ axis so whats it?

Comment: This means that the ratio of distance of $z$ from 1 and $i$ is constant, right ?

Comment: Yes you are right